# Image and Text alignment problem in CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to display the result like this: [Check this image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl1Ul.png)
What can I do make the text inside `<p id='info'>` responsive? Note: The whole text must be on the right side and must break the words in an overflown condition. Please help me.

When I tried to minimize the screen size of Chrom to check it's responsive-capability, it shows that the whole `#infohead1` breaks it's line instead of breaking wording inside `<p id='info'>`

```css
        .infoheader {
          background: rgb(187, 183, 183);
          padding: 6px;
          text-align: left;
        }
    
        #image {
          display: inline;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }
    
        #infohead1 {
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: middle;
    
        }
    
    
    
    
        #info {
          display: inline-block;
          word-wrap: break-word;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-family: 'Balsamiq Sans';
          cursor: pointer;
          padding: 1px;
    
        }
    
        #ans {
          color: rgb(0, 78, 33);
    
        }
    
    
        .img {
          cursor: pointer;
          width: 301px;
          border: 7px solid rgb(14, 14, 14);
          margin: 5px;
        }
```

```html
    
      <div class='infoheader'>
        <div id='image'>
          <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRu2w.png' alt='{{show_site}}' title='{{show_site}} - Homepage Interface'
            class='img'>
        </div>
        <div id='infohead1'>
          <p id='info' style='font-size:19px;'>Google Adsense Approval Probability: <span id='ans'>80%</span></p>
          <p id='info' style='font-size:19px;'>Total SEO Score: <span id='ans'>35%</span></p>
          <p id='info' style='font-size:19px;'>Site Structure Score: <span id='ans'>80%</span></p>
    
    
        </div>
    
      </div>
```

Comment: Look at [CSS Word break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) property and look at setting the containing element to a non-block Display Type ([flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Flexbox) or [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display))

Comment: What's the solution bro please

Comment: Check the links in my comment

Comment: Not working brother